# How to generate series indicator?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following dataset:

```
ObservationID  PreviousID    Chance     Success
1000               -           1           -
1001              1000         2           -
1002              1001         3           -
1003              1002         4           1
1004              1003         1           -
1005              1004         2           -
1006              1005         3           1
1007              1006         1           -
1008              1007         2           1
1009              1008         1           1
1010              1009         1           -        
1011              1010         2           -        
1012              1011         3           -        
1013              1012         4           -        
...
```

In the data, the individual participating is given four opportunities to progress within the game. If they succeed on any one of those chances, they are given another set of four opportunities to succeed, and 'Chance' resets to '1'. I am looking to make an indicator that shows which series of opportunities the individual is on.

```
ObservationID  PreviousID    Chance     Success   Series
1000               -           1           -        1
1001              1000         2           -        1
1002              1001         3           -        1
1003              1002         4           1        1
1004              1003         1           -        2
1005              1004         2           -        2
1006              1005         3           1        2
1007              1006         1           -        3
1008              1007         2           1        3
1009              1008         1           1        4
1010              1009         1           -        5
1011              1010         2           -        5
1012              1011         3           -        5
1013              1012         4           -        5
...
```

From there, I want to write in for every observation in that series whether or not they succeeded (as opposed to just on the last observation in the series).

```
ObservationID  PreviousID    Chance     Success   Series    Series Success
1000               -           1           -        1            1
1001              1000         2           -        1            1
1002              1001         3           -        1            1 
1003              1002         4           1        1            1
1004              1003         1           -        2            1
1005              1004         2           -        2            1
1006              1005         3           1        2            1
1007              1006         1           -        3            -
1008              1007         2           1        3            1
1009              1008         1           1        4            1
1010              1009         1           -        5            0
1011              1010         2           -        5            0
1012              1011         3           -        5            0
1013              1012         4           -        5            0
...
```

Is it possible to do this without using the unique identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(Series = cumsum(Chance == 1L)) %>%
  group_by(Series) %>%
  mutate(
    SeriesSuccess_lgl = any(Success == "1"),
    SeriesSuccess_int = +any(Success == "1"),
    SeriesSuccess_chr = if (any(Success == "1")) "1" else "-"
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 14 x 8
#    ObservationID PreviousID Chance Success Series SeriesSuccess_lgl SeriesSuccess_int SeriesSuccess_chr
#            <int> <chr>       <int> <chr>    <int> <lgl>                         <int> <chr>            
#  1          1000 -               1 -            1 TRUE                              1 1                
#  2          1001 1000            2 -            1 TRUE                              1 1                
#  3          1002 1001            3 -            1 TRUE                              1 1                
#  4          1003 1002            4 1            1 TRUE                              1 1                
#  5          1004 1003            1 -            2 TRUE                              1 1                
#  6          1005 1004            2 -            2 TRUE                              1 1                
#  7          1006 1005            3 1            2 TRUE                              1 1                
#  8          1007 1006            1 -            3 TRUE                              1 1                
#  9          1008 1007            2 1            3 TRUE                              1 1                
# 10          1009 1008            1 1            4 TRUE                              1 1                
# 11          1010 1009            1 -            5 FALSE                             0 -                
# 12          1011 1010            2 -            5 FALSE                             0 -                
# 13          1012 1011            3 -            5 FALSE                             0 -                
# 14          1013 1012            4 -            5 FALSE                             0 -
```

I offered three formats for `SeriesSuccess` because I tend to prefer the lowest R-native object that describes what I need. For instance, `_lgl` is a boolean/logical, and it is trivial to use in conditionals elsewhere; `_chr` is fine for reports and such, but using it for conditionals later on takes just a little more code.

(BTW: I think your expected `SeriesSuccess` for ID `1007` should be a `1` not `-`; if I'm wrong, please explain why.)

### base R

I find `ave` to be a *great* function, but one of its major side effects is that it retains the class of the original data regardless of what the `FUN`ction returns. For demonstration:

```r
dat$Series <- cumsum(dat$Chance == 1L)
head(dat)
#   ObservationID PreviousID Chance Success Series
# 1          1000          -      1       -      1
# 2          1001       1000      2       -      1
# 3          1002       1001      3       -      1
# 4          1003       1002      4       1      1
# 5          1004       1003      1       -      2
# 6          1005       1004      2       -      2

ave(dat$Success, dat$Series, FUN = function(z) any(z == "1"))
#  [1] "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "TRUE"  "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE"
```

So when I'm "stuck" using base R (vice tidyverse or `data.table`), I tend to work around it with something like this:

```r
# almost a perfect clone of stats::ave
ave2 <- function(x, ..., FUN = mean) {
    if (missing(...)) 
        x[] <- FUN(x)
    else {
      g <- interaction(...)
      ret <- lapply(split(x, g), FUN)
      split(x, g) <- ret
      class(x) <- class(ret[[1]])
    }
    x
}

ave2(dat$Success, dat$Series, FUN = function(z) any(z == "1"))
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
dat$SeriesSuccess <- ave2(dat$Success, dat$Series, FUN = function(z) any(z == "1"))
head(dat)
#   ObservationID PreviousID Chance Success Series SeriesSuccess
# 1          1000          -      1       -      1          TRUE
# 2          1001       1000      2       -      1          TRUE
# 3          1002       1001      3       -      1          TRUE
# 4          1003       1002      4       1      1          TRUE
# 5          1004       1003      1       -      2          TRUE
# 6          1005       1004      2       -      2          TRUE
```

(If `"TRUE"` the string is fine, then `ave` should work fine.)

Alternatives to this `ave` behavior depend. If it's always conversion of boolean, then `ave(...) == "TRUE"` will suffice, but integers, numerics, factors, dates, etc, will require slightly different mitigation steps. (Whereas `ave2` works for all of them.)

---

Data

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text= "
ObservationID  PreviousID    Chance     Success
1000               -           1           -
1001              1000         2           -
1002              1001         3           -
1003              1002         4           1
1004              1003         1           -
1005              1004         2           -
1006              1005         3           1
1007              1006         1           -
1008              1007         2           1
1009              1008         1           1
1010              1009         1           -        
1011              1010         2           -        
1012              1011         3           -        
1013              1012         4           -        ")
```

Comment: At first glance, this looks like it works! I used the dplyr option, and like the integer option best---however, when I run it, there are null values where I would like there to be 0s in column "SeriesSuccess" (your code is correct, I just inputted the table into stackoverflow  wrong--the original table just has "NA" values in the Success column instead of 0s). Is there a way to replace those null values in that SeriesSuccess column with 0s?

Comment: This sounds like it could be either `dat$Success == "1"` (lgl) or `+(dat$Success == "1")` (int). That would change the `SeriesSuccess` code to use `any(Success == 1L)` instead of `== "1"` (though technically `=="1"` will still work due to R's auto-coersion).